# What are the differences of Foundry vm.prank vs vm.broadcast

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, foundry

What are the differences of Foundry vm.prank vs vm.broadcast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`prank` sets `msg.sender` to the address provided to it.

`broadcast` actually creates transactions that can then be signed and sent on chain.

`broadcast` can be used to deploy contracts inside of scripts, for example I can grab my private key from my `.env` file and then deploy a contract with it.

```js
contract NFTScript is Script {

    function run() public {
        vm.startBroadcast(vm.envUint("PRIVATE_KEY"));
        NFT nft = new NFT("NonFun", "NFT");
        console2.log(address(nft));
        vm.stopBroadcast();
    }
}
```

`prank` can be used to ensure some tests pass, for example, any function that restricts the caller to a specific address.

```js
 function withdraw() public {
     require(msg.sender == owner);
}
```

This test would pass a function call to `withdraw`:

```js
function testCall() public {
vm.prank(owner);
myContract.withdraw(); 
}
```

Meanwhile, this test would also pass:

```js
function testBroadcast() public {
        vm.startBroadcast(owner);
        claim.withdraw();
        vm.stopBroadcast();
    }
```

Comment: But to call the withdraw function, isn't it required to be signed as well?

Comment: Which means that it's also possible for
```
vm.broadcast(owner)
myContract.withdraw()
```

Comment: @anonauditor Yes, you could also broadcast as the owner before calling withdraw and it would pass as well, I added another code snippet showing just that

Answer (score 0):

vm.prank: Sets the *next* call's msg.sender to be the input address

vm.broadcast: Using the address that calls the test contract, has the next call (at this call depth only) create a transaction that can later be signed and sent onchain